# Rails Controller/Model methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am watching Code School Rails testing course. There is an instance of the class `zombie`. The `zombie` model has a method:

```
def avatar_url
  ...
end
```

Within the test, `.rb` file has the following:

```
z.avatar_url
```

1. When I call a method like this, how does Rails distinguish if I'm calling a controller or model method? I hadn't thought of calling a model method from other than a controller, and  only like `Model.method` and not `object.method`.
2. If both my controller and my model have a method with the same name, how would Rails know which one to call?

**Update:**

Lets take the class String as example, it is not a model, right?

So I could say:

```
s = String.new
s.capitalize
```

If this call doesn't go to a model and not to a controller, where does it go then? Where would a class like String be defined in the Rails directory?

Comment: Remember you can call obj.class, e.g. `String.class` to see what it inherits from.  You can keep appending `.class` to get back to the base `Class` class

Comment: Ok thank you for the tip. Where in a rails folder would I define a custom class?

Comment: Custom classes go in `/lib` unless they depend upon Models or other things in `/app`

Comment: Ah I see, this is very enlightening! Thank you very much all of you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A method inside a controller can only be called via URL.
Example:

```
/things/super_action
```

Should call the `def super_action` inside `ThingsController`.

As for Model methods, they can be accessed anywhere. Just note if they are instance or class methods:

```
Model.ultra_method
```

This is a class method call, it is probably defined as `def self.ultra_method`.

```
m = Model.new
m.instance_method
```

This is a instance method call, and it is probably defined as `def ultra_method`.

**UPDATE**

`String` is a `core` class of `ruby` language. As is `Array`, `Number`, etc. In your example you are creating an `instance` of `String` and calling an `instance method` of the `String` class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Updated the answer. I recommend you to read about types of method in ruby. =]

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're new to Ruby as well as Rails. In Ruby, a class is sort of like a description of a type of object (although the class itself is an object, too). Whenever there is a class defined, you can create new instances of it, as with `String.new`.  Note that classes always have capitalized names.

Class methods are methods that work on the class itself. You can tell when a method is a class method because it will be attached to the capitalized name of the class (just like `String.new`). On the other hand, instance methods only work on an instance of the class, not on the class itself (eg `str = String.new; str.capitalize!`). Usually there are more instance methods than class methods, because instances are the things that you're actually working with (`new` is the most common class method you'll see).

As others have mentioned here, String is not a Rails model; it's a basic Ruby class. When you're working in Rails, you have access to all the regular Ruby classes as well as other classes and methods that are defined within Rails' source code. So String is not defined in Rails itself, but Rails does provide some useful instance methods for strings (eg `str.to_date`).

A model in Rails is really just a Ruby class. To understand the workings of a model, you should make sure you understand how Ruby classes work. What makes Rails models special is that they inherit from a class defined in Rails' source code known as ActiveRecord (any class in Ruby can inherit from another class, this is just one example of that). ActiveRecord has a number of class and instance methods, which are also available to your models because they inherit from ActiveRecord. For example, if you have a class (model) called Person, you can automatically use the `Person.find(id)` class method to look up a particular instance of the Person class in the database. You also have the `person.save` instance method to save the instance to the database.

All of this was confusing to me when I first started, so my best advice is to familiarize yourself with Ruby as you learn Rails.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, it seems to be clearer now. You're right, I'm new to Ruby as well, so there are some confusing parts.

Comment: Encourage you not to write "walls of text".  Paragraphs are everyones' friend

Comment: Sorry, typing on my phone. It's kind of cramped. Should be better now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can call Model class/instance methods from anywhere in Rails. Model are just the mapping to your database and acts as a proxy for your database. When you are calling

```
z.avatar_url
```

you are calling a method on "z" model instance. So not matter from where you call it will always call the model's method.

If you define a method with same name in both controller and model, you would always be calling a model's method with model instance or model class. Controller methods are simply action in Rails they are never referred directly from anywhere. They are used for Rails routing.

Hope I am clear.